# JavaScript setInterval() method not working as I expect it to

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm having an array of errors string, these errors are errors in a form after submitting.

I want to display these error as notification one by one after a fixed time, let say every 5 seconds.

The code that I have is:

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
recursive();

function recursive() {
  var error = array.pop();
  if (typeof error === 'undefined') {
    return;
  } else {
    console.log(error);
    //         showNoti(error);
  }
  setInterval(function() {
    recursive()
  }, 5000);
}
```

The problem with this code is that it's running fine in the first 2 iterations, printing out 5 after 5 seconds printing 6.

But at the third iteration, it prints both string 4 and 3. Similar to the fourth iteration.

How can I fix it so that it print each element in the array in every 5 seconds?

Comment: There's no jQuery at all in your code. It's all vanilla JavaScript. Anyway, the problem is that you're calling `setInterval` *inside* the function, which means after the first run, you have two intervals. Then three, etc.

Comment: `setInterval` has no relation to jquery

Comment: I edited the question title. I'm a beginner in scripting so sorry for that :)

Comment: Replace setInterval with setTimeout.... no? You want the function to stop once the array is exhausted.

Comment: When you run `recursive` once you would set up it up to execute every 5 seconds. So every 5 seconds you would get *another* copy of `recursive` running. t0 - `recursive` runs sets up interval; t1 (5 seconds later) - the interval executes `recursive` runs, sets up another interval; t2 - the two intervals execute, setting up two new intervals that will run `recursive`; t3 - four intervals execute, setting up 4 more intervals....and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, each call of `recursive` is initializing *another* interval. So, for example, after the first call, there will then be one interval running: after the second call, another interval will be initialized (two intervals), etc.

Put the `setInterval` outside the `recursive` instead:

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
recursive();

function recursive() {
  var error = array.pop();
  if (typeof error === 'undefined') {
    return;
  } else {
    console.log(error);
    //         showNoti(error);
  }
}
setInterval(function() {
  recursive()
}, 500);
```

Or use `setTimeout` instead:

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
recursive();

function recursive() {
  var error = array.pop();
  if (typeof error === 'undefined') {
    return;
  } else {
    console.log(error);
    //         showNoti(error);
  }
  setTimeout(recursive, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the `setInterval` outside of `recursive`. Every time you run `recursive`, you are creating a new `setInterval`

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
recursive();

function recursive() {
  var error = array.pop();
  if (typeof error === 'undefined') {
    return;
  } else {
    console.log(error);
    // showNoti(error);
  }
}

setInterval(recursive, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On all recursive calls, new setInterval is initialised. Move it out of recursive function or use `setTimeout`,

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
recursive();

function recursive() {
  var error = array.pop();
  if (typeof error === 'undefined') {
    return;
  } else {
    console.log(error);
    //         showNoti(error);
  }
}
 setInterval(function() {
    recursive()
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` will start an infinitely repeating timer.   In this case you are controlling whether you want it to repeat or not within your code.

That's what 'setTimeout' is for - a single delayed execution.

Change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
recursive();

function recursive() {
  var error = array.pop();
  if (typeof error === 'undefined') {
    return;
  } 
  console.log(error);
  setTimeout(function() {
    recursive()
  }, 5000);
}
```